# Error with connect SQL Developer with Oracle Database using Docker

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle-sqldeveloper, port

I am trying to install an oracle 18 database on my Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine using Docker. As seen in the following images, I have managed to obtain the database image and instantiate the content. To instantiate the container I have executed the following command:

```
sudo docker run \
--name oracle18c \
-p 1521:1521 \
-p 5500:5500 \
-e ORACLE_PDB=orcl \
-e ORACLE_PWD=password \
-e ORACLE_MEM=4000 \
-v /opt/oracle/oradata \
-d \
oracle/database:18.4.0-xe
```

[image]

[image]

With SQL Developer running, I try to create my first connection with the following parameters:

[image]

Could someone understand me or give me a solution to the problem?

FailureTest: listener refused the connection with the following error ora-12514.

Comment: Can you connect to Oracle from _inside_ the container?

Comment: I introduce these commands: sudo docker exec -it oracle18c bash    and  later   sqlplus sys@XEPDB1 as sysdba

Comment: Then, I introduce my password and I obtain the ERROR ORA-12154

Comment: To begin with, you specify the username as sys, not 'sys as sysdba', and you choose the sysdba role from the 'role' dropdown. Then you're asking for a service called orcl. connect to the VM and check what services the listener sees (lsnrctl stat).

Comment: did you find the solution?
I am able to connect from inside but not from sql developer.